# What is a tuple and tuple stream?

Tags: xml, xquery

Could any body tell me what is a "tuple" and a "tuple stream"? How many tuples are in this XML document? How we can list the first three tuples from this document?

```
<a>
    <b>
        <a/>
    </b>
    <c>
        <b/>
    </c>
</a>
```

Comment: This is not a valid XML document. The first `c` is probably a `<c/>`.

Comment: this is now in correct XML document

Comment: These terms are very general and can mean completely different things in different contexts. Where exactly did you encounter them? Are you reading the [XQuery Spec's definition of FLWOR expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-flwor-expressions)?

Comment: yes I am reading execution model for XQUERY.

Answer (score 9):

In the XQuery specification these terms are used exclusively to describe the semantics of [FLWOR expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-flwor-expressions). Since your example does not contain any FLWOR expressions, there are no tuples involved.

Consider instead the following query on your example document:

```
for $elem at $pos in /a//*
let $name := local-name($elem)
order by $name
return $pos
```

The first `for` clause emits a *tuple stream* of four tuples, one per iteration. Each tuple contains a binding for each variable declared in the FLWOR expression that is in scope:

```
($elem = <b><a/></b>, $pos = 1),
($elem = <a/>,        $pos = 2),
($elem = <c><b/></c>, $pos = 3),
($elem = <b/>,        $pos = 4)
```

The `let` clause then adds a binding for `$name` to each tuple, emitting the following stream:

```
($elem = <b><a/></b>, $pos = 1, $name = 'b'),
($elem = <a/>,        $pos = 2, $name = 'a'),
($elem = <c><b/></c>, $pos = 3, $name = 'c'),
($elem = <b/>,        $pos = 4, $name = 'b')
```

The `order by` clause finally takes the incoming stream and reorders the tuples according to the values bound to `$name`. The stream looks like this:

```
($elem = <a/>,        $pos = 2, $name = 'a'),
($elem = <b><a/></b>, $pos = 1, $name = 'b'),
($elem = <b/>,        $pos = 4, $name = 'b'),
($elem = <c><b/></c>, $pos = 3, $name = 'c')
```

The `return` clause returns the values bound to `$pos`, so the resulting value of the FLWOR expression is `(2, 1, 4, 3)` (or `(2, 4, 1, 3)` if the `order by` is not stable).